# Float List Issues: Removing Indentation

Tags: css, list, html-lists, css-float, indentation

So I've been trying to get floated lists to work right.

This
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8oXJ.png]

is what it's supposed to look like, but when I look at it with chrome or firefox I get this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNTzh.png]

I have no clue why this is happening. I've tried the list-style, margin and padding solutions, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/augzodia/Vz7Hs/1/
Because I can't post 3 hyperlinks yet.

Comment: Can you provide a live example (jsFiddle or similar) showing the problem?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it in jsFiddle (I included a link above) but I will see if I can host it somewhere.

Comment: Here's a live example: [link](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~atomanyih/ex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with an error in the CSS itself: what you're trying to do is correct. Replace this:

```
name .ul
```

With this:

```
.name ul
```

...and it works as expected. You should simplify your HTML if possible (there's no point giving each individual list item the same `class`). I've put an example [online here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/wP6Z3/).

Also, your declaration of `overflow: none` is incorrect. That's not valid: use `hidden` or `auto` for the purpose of clearing your floats. Accepted values

`overflow: visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually that was a typo, but in my original code I had ul.name which didn't work either. Do you mind explaining the why div.name does what I want but not ul.name?

Comment: `ul.name` is perfectly valid as well: are you sure that your unordered list had the class applied, and not just the parent `div`?